# Creating a New Command w/ 4 Arguments for Quickly Referencing the Gradient Equation?

Tags: macros, arguments

I'm trying to create a new command of the form,

```
\gradeq{T,x,y,z}
```

That takes the four arguments provided and displays,

```
\pdv{T}{x}\xhat + \pdv{T}{y}\yhat + \pdv{T}{z}\zhat
```

This is how I've tried it,

```
\newcommand{\gradeq}[4]{\pdv{#1}{#2}\xhat + \pdv{#1}{#3}\yhat + \pdv{#1}{#4}\zhat}
```

I've tried with extra curly braces as someone recommended in another question, and I've tried placing the command within $ ... $.

I get a whole list of errors. The full test document is,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{physics}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Summary}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Outline}

% Frequently Used Math Symbols

% VECTORS
\newcommand{\xhat}{\hat{x}}
\newcommand{\yhat}{\hat{y}}
\newcommand{\zhat}{\hat{z}}

% VECTOR OPERATORS
\newcommand{\gradeq}[4]{\pdv{#1}{#2}\xhat + \pdv{#1}{#3}\yhat + \pdv{#1}{#4}\zhat}

\begin{document}

$\gradeq{T,x,y,z}$

\end{document}
```

And I receive the following errors, (All on line 25)

```
! Missing } inserted.
! Too many }'s. \frac #1#2->{\begingroup #1\endgroup \@@over #2}
! Missing $ inserted.
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
```

Note that the *\xhat* commands work in other documents, and *\pdv* is a command provided in the *physics* package that is meant to give the partial derivative in fraction form.

I'm brand new to LaTeX, so I'm sure I'm doing a whole host of things incorrectly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hi and welcome in the **TeX.SE** community. The mistake is for the command `\gradeq`. You should to use `$\gradeq{T}{x}{y}{z}$` instead to put the commas `$\gradeq(T,x,y,z)$` when you introduced many arguments. After it is not preferible to use `physics` package for problem for the spacing and unusual macro.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{physics}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Summary}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Outline}

% Frequently Used Math Symbols

% VECTORS
\newcommand{\xhat}{\hat{x}}
\newcommand{\yhat}{\hat{y}}
\newcommand{\zhat}{\hat{z}}

% VECTOR OPERATORS
\newcommand{\gradeq}[4]{\pdv{#1}{#2}\xhat + \pdv{#1}{#3}\yhat + \pdv{#1}{#4}\zhat}

\begin{document}

$\gradeq{T}{x}{y}{z}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you for the quick and easy to comprehend response.

Comment: Hi, remember that I am a scarce user :-).....especially in English language because I'm an Italian native speaker. If you have understood my synthetic explanation I am very very happy. Best regards.